# Rendering image with PHP using readfile()

Tags: php

I'm trying to display an image from a file in PHP using the following snippet as a starting point.

The snippet just takes a file name, reads the file, and outputs it with the correct Mime-Type.

```
# Definimos la ruta del directorio privado.
# Este es el directorio con permisos de escritura.
$ruta = './images';
$filename = 'Desert.jpg';
# El nombre del archivo que se desea servir, lo obtendremos
# mediante el parámetro 'file' que luego será pasado por la URI
$file = isset($filename) ? $ruta . "/" . $filename : NULL;

# Verificamos el valor de $file
# Si no es NULL, verificamos si el archivo existe antes de proceder
if(!is_null($file)) {
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        # Creamos un recurso fileinfo para obtener el tipo MIME
        $resource = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        # Obtenemos el tipo MIME
        $mimetype = finfo_file($resource, $file);
        # Cerramos el recurso
        finfo_close($resource);
        # Modificamos los encabezados HTTP
        header("Content-Type: $mimetype");
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        # Leemos y mostramos el archivo
        readfile($file);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't get it to work. I've verified that the `fileinfo` extension is enabled and I don't see any errors, the image just doesn't display.

Any ideas?

Comment: Edited to clarify the question a little. Hope it helps you get an answer.

Comment: Have you checked the actual response you're getting from the server? (look at your network tab in your browser). Are you getting a PHP error? A wrong header?

Comment: The function [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) returns the mime type and it's included in the PHP core, you don't need any extension for it.

Answer (score 0):

before the line with

```
readfile($file);
```

I uses

```
ob_clean();
```

for clear the buffer and works correctly, relly I don't need extra modules for mime type i used [mime_content_type too()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mime-content-type.php).

!thanks a lot!